# How to detect swipe action on an ImageView which is inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, gesture

I have an an Imageview which is inside a ScrollView. I want to detect SWIPE UP & SWIPE DOWN gestures on it. Is it possible to do it?
Using `SimpleOnGestureListener` I could able to detect SWIPE LEFT & SWIPE RIGHT.